# Ruby can't 'put', gives error 'Unknown function puts'

Tags: ruby, puppet

First off, I'm a ruby noob and I'm in a bit over my head, please be gentile.

I'm getting an exception on line 14 of this file, (written by someone else).

https://github.com/theforeman/kafo/blob/master/modules/kafo_configure/manifests/yaml_to_class.pp

```
  if is_hash($kafo_configure::params[$name]) {
    # The quotes around $classname seem to matter to puppet's parser...
    $params = { "${classname}" => $kafo_configure::params[$name] }
    create_resources( 'class', $params )
```

I need to adding a debugging to determine why the 'create_resources' function call is crashing.

```
exception object expected at /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems\
/kafo-0.6.0/modules/kafo_configure/manifests/yaml_to_class.pp:14 on node foo.bar
```

When I try and print out the value of $name, I encounter an error that 'puts' is an unknown function.

```
  if is_hash($kafo_configure::params[$name]) {
    puts "debugging name is #{name}"
    # The quotes around $classname seem to matter to puppet's parser...
    $params = { "${classname}" => $kafo_configure::params[$name] }
    create_resources( 'class', $params )
```

I've also tried the following syntaxes:

```
    puts "debugging name is #{name}"
    print "debugging name is #{name}"
    puts "debugging name is $name"
    print "debugging name is $name"
    puts "debugging name is #{$name}"
```

Can anyone explain:
1. Why this function is unable to print/put ?
2. Is there another way to show what the value of that $name variable is?

**Update**

As pointed out, I've also used this syntax `puts "debugging name is #{$name}"`

Comment: I don't see it from that 4 lines. Add to them then, to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: This is not Ruby — it looks like Perl. Er, correction, from looking at the file, it looks like it's Puppet's manifest language. At any rate, not Ruby.

Comment: It's not Perl. It's the Puppet DSL. Ruby is a no go there. you can use something like `$foo = inline_template("<%= puts 'foo' %>")`. I don't remember what log file this would write to though.

Comment: @Chuck: Sorry, just realized you noticed it was Puppet. My bad :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `notice` function for printing debugging messages.

The `fail` function you've pointed out will print the message, but will also break the manifest execution.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Since puppet is written in ruby, I mistakenly assumed that I could use ruby inside of the puppet file.

I was able to print out the debuging statement I needed using puppet's built in 'fail' function

```
fail("if the value of name is ${name}")
```

Working solution

```
if is_hash($kafo_configure::params[$name]) {
# The quotes around $classname seem to matter to puppet's parser...
fail("if the value of name is ${name}")
$params = { "${classname}" => $kafo_configure::params[$name] }
create_resources( 'class', $params )
```

Comment: `Since puppet is written in ruby, I mistakenly assumed that I could use ruby inside of the puppet file.`  Normally, that would not be a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

To make debug messages visible on the agent side, you can employ the `notify { }` resource type.